# Protect video with password

Tags: video, passwords, privacy

Are they any method to protect video files with a password, so the player will ask for the password before playback?

Currently I am protecting private video files using zip compression with a password but it is very inconvenient. I am forced to uncompress huge files each time before watching, and than erase it using special utilities (to avoid further restoring).

Comment: Don't make assumptions - I can think of many situations where this would be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org)?  Create a volume, put all your files in there and password-protect the volume.  There's no compression, so it should be pretty fast to access the files.

Answer (score 1):

There are some 3rd party tools ([Androsa](http://blogote.com/2009/softwares/password-protect-video-files.html), [Video Sanctuary](http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/how-to-encrypt-or-password-protect-videos-files/)) for this out there, but I have never tried any. As Bobby said, they may be dangerous and it's your decision to try or not to try them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I've never heard of built-in encryption in video files.

Though, there are quiet some DRM solutions out there, but they all cost money and you don't want even one of them on your PC (some of them behaving like Trojans and even opening backdoors for real viruses).

Answer (score -1):

Try **[Encrypt Files](http://www.encryptfiles.net/)**

Features :

```
* Fast and lightweight
* 13 advanced encryption algorithms
* It can encrypt entire folders
* Shreds original files after encryption
* Make files hidden after encryption
* It is free
```

Hope it helps.